# Get FragmentManager inside AndroidViewModel

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragmentmanager, android-architecture-components

`AndroidViewModel` is used to access `Application` context. I'm trying to access `Activity`'s `FragmentManager` without passing it explicitly:

```
class FooViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
  private val fm = (app.applicationContext as Activity).fragmentManager
  ..
}
```

Getting error, unable to cast `Context` to `Activity`.

---

**Question**: is there any way to get `FragmentManager` inside `AndroidViewModel` without passing it explicitly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think short answer will be **"no, there is no way"**, because `Application` context is in no aware of `FragmentManager`.

`FragmentManager` is an object that subclasses of `FragmentActivity` may have. `Application` is not a subclass of `FragmentActivity`.

Another question would be, why would you ever need a `FragmentManager` instance inside your `ViewModel`? Most possibly you should delegate view-related stuff to handle to other unit other than `ViewModel` (e.g. `Activity`, `Fragment`). Keep in mind, that this `ViewModel` would be retained over configuration change, thus if you keep a reference to the `FragmentManager` inside your `ViewModel`, you'd be leaking your `Activity` instance.